# Insertion Sort in java and am having difficulty accounting for some odd behavior

Tags: java, algorithm, insertion-sort

I have coded an implementation of Insertion Sort in java and am having difficulty accounting for some odd behavior.

Here is my code:

```
package algorithm.insertionsort;

public class InsertionSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 202, 1, 400, 0, 12};
        int[] sortedArray = insertionSort(array);

        for (int element : sortedArray) {
            System.out.print("" + element + " ");
        }

    }

    public static int[] insertionSort(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            int element = a[i];
            int j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && a[j] > element) {
                a[j + 1] = a[j];
                j--;
            }
            a[j + 1] = element;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

This is the output :

```
0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 202 400 12
```

Why is that final element excluded from the sort?

Comment: Debugger..................

Answer (score 3):

You have a small typo in your loop:

`for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {` should become...

`for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {`

When fixed this way, you will be iterating over the whole array (aside from the first element), instead of the range between the element at index 1 and the penultimate element (where `12`, the last element, is left out).

**Output** (fixed)

```
0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12 202 400
```

Answer (score 3):

because you loop from `index = 1` to `index < length - 1` for that 12 is excluded :

```
{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 202, 1 , 400, 0, 12}
     ^__________________________________^
```

Instead you have to loop from `index = 1` to `index < length` :

```
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
```

now the range of the iteration is :

```
{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 202, 1 , 400, 0, 12}
     ^______________________________________^
```

Comment: Now, when I change to a.length instead of a.length - 1, when this range is sorted:
   [code] new int[] { 9, 9, 9, 8, 7, 73, 32, 109, 1100, 432, 321, 0 }[code]
The result is:
 [code]   9 0 7 8 9 9 32 73 109 321 432 1100[code]